# Reference for Fredholm's alternative

Tags: partial-differential-equations, operator-theory

i need a reference for my thesis. It concerns Fredholm's alternative in the following form:

Let $\mathfrak{L}$ be a self-adjoint operator in a Hilbert space $H$ with a scalar product $\left< \cdot, \cdot\right>_{H}$ .

Then either the equation

$\mathfrak{L}(u)=f$ has a solution $u$

or

$\left<f,u_{0} \right>_{H} =1 $ for all solutions of the equation $\mathfrak{L}\left(u_{0}\right)=0$

This version of Fredholm's alternative was stated in this discussion: [How to use the Fredholm alternative in an ODE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/414998/how-to-use-the-fredholm-alternative-in-an-ode).

Does anyone know a reference for this version of Fredholm's alternative?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: It is just the standard Fredholm alternative. You can find it in many PDEs books, for example, at the top of page 408 in Habermans [_Applied Partial Differential Equations_.](https://www.amazon.com/Applied-Differential-Equations-Boundary-Problems/dp/032179706X)

Comment: Thank you very much for your helpful response.